# steroids.js how to disable navigation bar by default and on loading page

Tags: ios, cordova, ios6, ios7, steroids

steroids on iOS6 and iOS7

After `WebView` loaded `navigationBar` is shown a several milliseconds before device ready event is trggered and called

```
steroids.view.navigationBar.hide();
```

On loadind page `navigationBar` also is shown.

How to disable `navigationBar` in this cases?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer.
You just need to push new webView with option `navigationBar: false`:

```
steroids.layers.push({
  view: webViewObject,
  navigationBar: false
}
```